# Possible to host .NET Core App inside IIS Site's Application?

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, iis-7.5

I know it's possible to use an IIS Site to host a .NET Core App, and it's pretty easy. However, I need to host it inside an Application within that site.

I follow the guide set forth here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x

When I follow the guide and use a Site as the host, it works flawlessly. However, when I try to host the .Net Core app inside of an Application *inside* of that Site, I get configuration errors, such as errors in my web.config that complain about a duplicate entry for , even if I change the name or comment it out in my web.config.

What is the process to host a .NET Core App inside of an IIS Application inside of an IIS Site, if it's possible?

[image: Goal of where I want to host the app]

Answer (score 0):

I had seen others say to "Edit the web.config file higher up in the hierarchy" but I was not able to find it. I was finally able to locate it, by using the "Content view" on in IIS, right clicking on the main site's web.config, going to the location in File Explorer, and commenting out the duplicate entry there.

Comment: "Commenting out the duplicate entry" is the worst way. Learn how to add a `<remove>` tag before it. You also need to track it back to your code base, so as to make the changes there. Otherwise, the issue would happen again if you re-publish the app.

Comment: @LexLi I did not include a web.config in my code base, it was generated at publish time. I tried adding a `<remove/>` before it, and even a `<clear/>` but that did not work. I now have two applications running on it, and have published each several times without any issues. They also came back up successfully after restarting the server.

Comment: like I said you need to learn the proper syntax. If you put a web.config in your project, then the generated copy would not be used.

Comment: I tried that as well, as a matter of fact, utilizing the same strategy as my previous comment, and it did not work. What is your suggestion, if you believe the way I'm doing it is not best practice?

Comment: I gave an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to your project in Visual Studio, and create a `web.config` file at its root,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> Remember to modify its strings to match your own web app (like `arguments`).

The extra `<remove>` tag here should avoid the configuration error of duplicate items.

By putting your own `web.config` there, it also stops Visual Studio or `dotnet publish` from creating such a file for you. The generated copy from them misses the `<remove>` tag.